# Android ListView dynamically Load more items(from MysqlDatabase) when scroll to the Bottom

Tags: listview, android-listview, expandablelistview

How to detect end of list when scrolling and trigger loading of more data from a WEB request into a ListView

If you are loading data from a WEB server and the list is huge, then the practical solution would be to load a certain amount and if the user scrolls to the end of the list, load some more and keep going until you load the full list

Answer (score 0):

You can add paging listener to your ListView:
1. Implement `AbsListView.OnScrollListener`, for example you can create

abstract class `InfiniteListViewPaging`

```
 public abstract class InfiniteListViewPaging implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    private static final String TAG = InfiniteListViewPaging.class.getName();
    public ListView mListView;
    public View mFooterView;
    private boolean mCanLoadMore;
    private boolean mIsLoading;

    /**
     * Should be created before setting the adapter on the {@code listView} as this sets the
     * {@link android.widget.ListView#addFooterView(android.view.View)} on it.
     * @param context
     * @param listView
     */
    public InfiniteListViewPaging(Context context, ListView listView) {
        mFooterView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.footer_list_view, null);
        mListView = listView;
        listView.addFooterView(mFooterView, null, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                         int totalItemCount) {
        boolean lessThanOneScreenLeftToScrollDown = (totalItemCount - 2 * visibleItemCount) <= firstVisibleItem;
        if (mCanLoadMore && !mIsLoading && lessThanOneScreenLeftToScrollDown) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Load Next Page!");
            mIsLoading = true;
            loadMore();
        }
    }

    public void setCanLoadMore(boolean canLoadMore) {
        mCanLoadMore = canLoadMore;
        mFooterView.setVisibility(canLoadMore ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }

    public abstract void loadMore();

    public void hasFinishedLoading() {
        mIsLoading = false;
    }
```

2. And then in your Activity(or Fragment), when initialize ListView set

   ```
   mListPaging = new InfiniteListViewPaging(this, getListView()) {
                       @Override
                     public void loadMore() {
                          loadMore();
                      } 
   }; 
   mListView.setOnScrollListener(mListPaging);
   ```